# Solana Signature verification failed

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli

the contract code is:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DepositToken<'info> {
    /// 项目方
    #[account(mut)]
    pub b_user: Signer<'info>,
    /// Token x mint for ex. USDC
    pub x_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// ATA of x_mint
    #[account(mut, constraint = b_x_token.mint == x_mint.key() && b_x_token.owner == b_user.key())]
    pub b_x_token: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(init, payer = b_user, space = Escrow::LEN)]
    pub escrow: Account<'info, Escrow>,

    #[account(
    init,
    payer = b_user,
    token::mint = x_mint,
    token::authority = escrow,
    )]
    pub escrowed_x_tokens: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn deposit(ctx: Context<DepositToken>, x_amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let escrow = &mut ctx.accounts.escrow;
        let (pda, _bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[ESCROW_PDA_SEED], ctx.program_id);
        escrow.authority = pda;
        escrow.escrowed_x_tokens = ctx.accounts.escrowed_x_tokens.key();
        anchor_spl::token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                anchor_spl::token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.b_x_token.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.escrowed_x_tokens.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.b_user.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            x_amount,
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

the ts code is :

```
const tx = await program.methods.deposit(new anchor.BN(1))
            .accounts({
                bUser: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                xMint: x_mint.publicKey,
                bXToken: project_x_token,
                escrow: escrow,
                escrowedXTokens: escrowedXTokens.publicKey,
                tokenProgram: splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
            }).signers([escrowedXTokens]).rpc().catch((err) => {
                console.log("err:", err);
            });
        console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
```

the error msg is :

```
err: Error: Signature verification failed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print the transaction to see which public keys are missing signatures. Looks like here you should be passing in the Keypair of the Escrow you're initializing.

Comment: As mentioned by @Truitt, the `Escrow` account needs to be included in the signers array since an account is required to sign during its creation.

Answer (score 0):

You must sign the transaction with **b_user's** keypair .